# Date Handling and Conversion

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

How to handle date of type 10-January-2023 in python and pandas

I need to convert from format

10 January 2023 to format 10-01-2023.

I have tried pd.datetime() but not able to achieve desired output.

Answer (score 0):

:Assuming you have a date string `'10 January 2023'`, first convert it to datetime type:

```
dt = '10 January 2023'
dt_py = datetime.strptime(dt, '%d %B %Y')
```

then convert back to string format you want:

```
dt = dt_py.strftime('%d-%m-%Y')
```

So putting it all together:

```
from datetime import datetime

dt = '10 January 2023'
dt = datetime.strptime(dt, '%d %B %Y').strftime('%d-%m-%Y')
```

If you are getting date string in a dataframe column, you can apply a lambda function to do the above:

```
df['Datetime'] = df['DateTime'].apply(lambda x: datetime.strptime(x, '%d %B %Y').strftime('%d-%m-%Y'))
```

You can also use the to_datetime function to input the date using `format='%d %B %Y'` argument, but you would then again need a lambda function to convert it back to the string format you want.